# Post files from SharePoint Online to Yammer

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, yammer

We are currently testing Office 365, this time, we are focused in Yammer.
When we try to post a file in Yammer, from SharePoint Online, the list is empty, and its shows: SharePoint isn't responding right now. Check back soon.

Best regards
Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  We have been running Yammer with SharePoint for a number of years but recently it's stopped working with the same error message SharePoint isn't responding right now. Check back soon."

Comment: This is not an answer to the question @Alejandro asked. You might want to delete the answer and post your comment as 'comment' to the original question.